# Javascript Popup Losing Focus in Some Cases

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This has been absolutely baffling me. The following code works:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openPopUp('Edit_Screen.aspx?Image_Id='+ '<%# Eval("Image_Id") %>','Popup',850,800);">
                         <%# Eval("ReferenceNumber") %>
</a>
```

Which calls this:

```
function openPopUp(pageURL, title, popupWidth, popupHeight) {
  var targetPop = null;
  var left = (screen.width / 2) - (popupWidth / 2);
  var top = (screen.height / 2) - (popupHeight / 2);
  targetPop = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, status=no, menubar=no, width=' + popupWidth + ', height=' + popupHeight + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left).focus();

}
```

This code does not work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewRecord" runat="server" Text="Enter New Record" CssClass = "button" OnClientClick="LaunchImage()" />
```

Which calls this:

```
function LaunchImage()
{
   debugger;
   openPopUp("Insert_Screen.aspx?dataType=images", "Popup", 750, 650);
}
```

And that calls the same openPopUp function that was shown above. The first a href code example calls the popup and keeps the focus on the popup. The second, which is called from the ASP button, calls the popup, and then gives the focus back to the screen that called it. Does anyone have any idea why? This has been baffling me for awhile now.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

A click on the button causes a postback, while a click on the anchor link does not. You can prevent the postback by returning false in the `OnClientClick` event of the button:

```
OnClientClick="LaunchImage(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewRecord" runat="server" Text="Enter New Record" CssClass = "button" OnClientClick="LaunchImage(); return false;" />
```

or

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewRecord" runat="server" Text="Enter New Record" CssClass = "button" OnClientClick="return LaunchImage();" />
```

and javascript

```
function LaunchImage()
{
   debugger;
   openPopUp("Insert_Screen.aspx?dataType=images", "Popup", 750, 650);
   return false;
}
```